# new FileReader(); react. when iterating over items

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have a list of files, for which I want to find the base64Data and display it in a list for each file.

I have tried the following, but it doesn't work, the main reason, I guess, being `reader.onload` is asynchronous.

My code looks like the following

```
const App = () => {

  // code....
  <ul>
    {Array.from(files).map(file) => {
      const reader = new FileReader();
      let base64Data;
      reader.onload = (event: any) => {
      // I want to use the result here to display 
      // the Base64 data string of file
         console.log(event.target.result);
         base64Data = event.target.result
      };

       reader.readAsDataURL(file);
       return <p>{base64Data}</p>;
    }}
  </ul>
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't be doing logic like that in render, do it in a lifecycle method like componentDidMount (or higher up where you set the file list) and set the result to state for example. You can show a loading indicator until you set the base64 to state. P.S. it's more efficient to use blob urls than converting binary to base64 but remember to release the urls on unmount

Comment: thanks @Dominic, makes sense

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```html
// You should load data before rendering. You can't use async functions for render

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    
    this.state = {
      bases: [],
    };
  }
  
  async componentDidMount() {
     const {files} = this.props; // Assuming you get files from props
     
     const promises = files.map((blob) => {            
        return new Promise((res) => {
          const reader = new FileReader();
          reader.readAsDataURL(blob);

          reader.onload = (e) => {
            res(e.target.result);
          }        
        });            
     });
     
     const bases = await Promise.all(promises);
     
     this.setState({bases});
  }
  
  render() {
     const {bases} = this.state;
     
     if (bases.length === 0) return 'No data';
     
     
    <ul>
      {bases.map(base64Data) => {
         return <li>{base64Data}</li>;
      }}
    </ul>
  }
}
```

Comment: Fair enough. Done.